# Add Keyboard Shortcut to MenuBar command AppKit macOS

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

How do I add a keyboard shortcut to an existing menubar command in a macOS AppKit app. Specifically, I would like to make the Delete shortcut under Edit work when I press command delete.

How do I add a keyboard shortcut to the existing command?

Thanks, Dev_101

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you want to add the shortcut later? Post the code you tried please.